# SMTP Server localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have developed a WEB application for my company. All users access it via intranet. How can I configure a SMTP server to use only the intranet, since we don't have internet access in the company, thank you for you support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a mail server is a complex task. It depends on your server os and your requirements. There are many tutorials on the internet.

Example mail servers on Linux are Postfix or Exim. On Windows you can try Mercury. Mercury is also shipped with XAMPP.

Comment: The server is apache running on Windows XP. Any good tutorial woul be very appreciated! Thank you

Comment: On Windows you can try Mercury. Mercury is also shipped with XAMPP. Since you are using Windows XP, security does not matter and you can use it with XAMPP.

Comment: Ok I'll try it thank you! So I just need to run XAMMp and activate the Mercury? Then PHP mail should wotk?

Comment: That _should_ work with default settings, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've used postfix for sending mail on a local network and dovecot to provide POP and IMAP mail collection.

You don't need to have a real domain name to set this up.

There are lots of HOWTOs that can show you how to set them up:

http://www.google.com/search?q=dovecot+postfix+local+mail

Comment: That is not possible without an internet connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my site is running on a machine in the local intranet.  What is my SMTP domain? On my php.ini is localhost.